# Click Element with Selenium python

Tags: css, python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium

I am trying to click a button using Selenium.

Below is the code

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text"> … </span>
    </button>
```

I tried to do this by the css selector:

```
clickbutton=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-only")
```

**My error: Unable to locate element: { method: "css selector","selector":"button.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-only"} **

Am I approaching this wrong? Im not understanding the error. Shoud I use another Locator?

Comment: do you really need to target all those classes? what if you do `ui-dialog-buttonset button.ui-button`

Comment: still doesn't work when I tried those

Comment: is there more than one of those buttons? or have you tried using `find_element_by_class_name`?

Comment: Theres 2 buttons a "create" button (the button I am trying to click) and a close button. I have tried driver.find_element_by_class_name ("ui-dialog_buttonset")

Comment: i see. do you know xpath?

Comment: nope. I have looked it up but I'm not sure of how it applies here

Comment: I think it is related to `aria-disabled`, your css seems ok. see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your css selector is ok the problem is related to html code which setting `aria-disabled="false"` for compability. For Web3 [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-disabled) it means that related element and descandent are active but in your case it is not working.

Simple you can set the `aria-disabled="true"` then you can interact with the button but even you set it back to `false` it still works. To change the button attribute, you can use `execute_script`. Alternative to your css you use this css too: `.ui-dialog-buttonset > button`

```
>>> dr.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-dialog-buttonset > button").get_attribute("aria-disabled")
u'false'
>>> dr.execute_script('document.querySelector(".ui-dialog-buttonset > button").setAttribute("aria-disabled", true)')
>>> dr.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-dialog-buttonset > button").get_attribute("aria-disabled")
u'true'
>>> dr.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-dialog-buttonset > button").click()
```